# Tcl: [info level] vs. [info frame]

Tags: tcl

What is the difference between frames and levels of execution?

I wrote a small example to find out. I realized that the level number was incremented every time a proc was called.

On the other hand, the frame number was incremented on every

- proc call
- source command
- eval command
- etc.

For this reason, I started to think of levels as of a subset of frames. Now I'm debugging some real-life code and I realized that the level number can increase without the frame number being increased too. How to make sense of this stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack levels, which is what `info level` talks about, are the important ones, because they're the ones that you can use `upvar` and `uplevel` to access into. This means that the Tcl “stack“ is *really* a tree, since you can use `uplevel` to go up to a higher level and start a new branch, with each step deeper being taken by a call to a procedure (or procedure-like thing) or a call to `namespace eval`; the `info level` command really talks about the current branch traced all the way back to the root.

The `info frame` command walks the tree of frames rather differently — I think it uses the *actual* way in which they are stacked, with frames being able to appear twice — and reports very different information about each of those frames. Personally, I only really find that it is useful for debugging.

Let's try a *simple* example. This is an interactive session.

```
% proc foo {y} {set x 1;bar $y $x $y}
% proc bar {a b args} {
    puts [info level 0]
    puts [info level -1]
    puts [info frame 0]
    puts [info frame -1]
}
% foo 3
bar 3 1 3
foo 3
type proc line 4 cmd {info frame 0} proc ::bar level 0
type proc line 1 cmd {bar $y $x $y} proc ::foo level 1
```

OK, as you can see, `info level` is reporting the *actual* values that were used and does not report itself, whereas `info frame` is reporting what that level is currently doing.

Here's a more complex example:

```
% proc foo {y} {set x 1;grill $y $x $y}
% proc grill {a b c} {uplevel 1 [list bar $a $b $c]}
% proc bar {args} {
    for {set i 1} {$i<=[info level]} {incr i} {puts $i-->[info level $i]}
    for {set i 1} {$i<=[info frame]} {incr i} {puts $i==>[info frame $i]}
}
% foo 3
1-->foo 3
2-->bar 3 1 3
1==>type eval line 1 cmd {foo 3} level 2
2==>type proc line 1 cmd {grill $y $x $y} proc ::foo level 1
3==>type proc line 1 cmd {uplevel 1 [list bar $a $b $c]} proc ::grill
4==>type eval line 1 cmd {bar 3 1 3} proc ::grill
5==>type proc line 3 cmd {info frame $i} proc ::bar level 0
```

As you can see, `info level` *does not see* that the `uplevel` happened, but `info frame` *does*. But only `info level` can really tell you what the arguments are. (Note that if you put the code in a file that you `source`, `info frame` reports *even more* information.)