# Embedded Tcl: How to detect the evaluation of expression?

Tags: embedded, tcl, expression, evaluation

We have a Tcl **built in** our C/C++ application, there is a place in our code where we have to check whether the command is **nested** which means command result is set later like: "**::Tcl_SetResult(...)**". If not, it is printed to console or redirected it to a file using "**printMessage(...)**".

Unfortunately, something like **::Tcl_GetCommandInfo**, does not provide much information. (I have to admit I'm clueless in Tcl).

Example: (How the function looks like, Tcl calls it then we process data and it comes back to Tcl, Tcl decides if it is our command or not and proceed):

> *void traceProc(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp* pInterp, int nLevel, char* pszCommand, Tcl_CmdProc* pCmdProc, ClientData
>   cmdCliendData, int argc, char* argv[])*

The problem can be seen when executing **our_command**:

```
our_command; # -> nLevel == 1
if {[our_command] eq "sth"} {do_sth}; # -> also nLevel == 1
```

Right now, I expect nLevel to be 2 cause it is inside if statement or the first one to be 0 or some kind of additional information about current executed command. Am I doing something wrong? The thing is I don't know what to do later because I "shouldn't" print command result if it is inside `[]` brackets etc.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, I am afraid. Can you pls. provide a minimal, working example of a C program (a C-implemented Tcl command?) that exercises `Tcl_SetResult` and `Tcl_GetCommandInfo` in the way described? What is the expected outcome, based on whether "the command" is executed as part of a scripted `if` or not?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Tentative answer (on actual question)

As pointed out before, there is no way to detect a nested evaluation of a given command (proc) reliably by introspecting on the command or call frames. In addition, this requires access to Tcl internals (private headers, etc.) and it is only available for Tcl 8.6+ (if this matters to you). The case of `if`-ed and non-`if` calls onto your command (`myCommand`) could be detected, at least for what you have revealed to us, by doing sth like:

```
CmdFrame *framePtr;
Interp *iPtr = ((Interp *)interp);
Tcl_Obj* resObj = Tcl_NewIntObj(1);

framePtr = iPtr->cmdFramePtr;
Tcl_ResetResult(interp);

 if (iPtr->cmdFramePtr->nextPtr &&
     iPtr->cmdFramePtr->nextPtr->framePtr ==
     iPtr->cmdFramePtr->framePtr &&
     iPtr->cmdFramePtr->framePtr == iPtr->varFramePtr) {
     Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, resObj);
 } else {
     fprintf(stderr, "The result is %s\n", Tcl_GetString(resObj));
 }
 return TCL_OK;
```

A script then executes as follows:

```
myCommand; # w/ print-out
set y [myCommand]; # w/ print-out
if {[myCommand]} { puts "then, here!"} else {puts "notok"}; # w/o print-out
```

However, you will notice that one cannot differentiate between the following two `if`-inner uses:

```
if {[myCommand]} { puts "then, here! [myCommand]" } else {puts "notok"}
```

The second one will not print-out either. Only an (artificially created) extra frame on the command stack will do that:

```
if {[myCommand]} { puts "then, here! [apply {{} {myCommand}}]"} else {puts "notok"};
```

So, this approach does not generalise, as demonstrated by example.

### Suggestion for improvement

> "I shouldn't print command result if it is inside [] brackets etc."

I would like to return to one of Donal's suggestions, and demonstrate, how you could easily disentangle the different usage contexts of your command (`myCommand`) by providing two separate commands, one for each context, while preserving the look'n'feel of having a single one. You can provide a main one that computes the intended return value, and provide an auxiliary wrapper which "redirects" the return value to stdout (or whatever).

(1) Main command: Turn you existing, C-implemented command into one that does *not* print the result value, but returns the result using `Tcl_SetObjResult` only. Place this command (or, alias it into) the [`::tcl::mathfunc::*`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcl%3A%3Amathfunc) namespace. Using [Critcl](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Critcl), this might look like so:

```
critcl::ccommand ::tcl::mathfunc::myCommand {cd interp objc objv} {
    Tcl_Obj* resObj = Tcl_NewIntObj(1);
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, resObj);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

(2) Create a scripted wrapper in the top-level (`::`) or project-specific namespace that bears the same (unqualified) name `myCommand`:

```
proc ::myCommand {} {
    puts stdout [uplevel 1 ::tcl::mathfunc::myCommand]
    return
}
```

The wrapper calls out to the main command and `puts` the result wherever one wants. `return` will reset the interpreter's result. Alternatively, you may also have it returned, so the wrapper becomes contract-equivalent with the main command.

You can now use `myCommand` differently, in an `[expr]` environment like `[if]` conditions and non-`expr` ones:

```
myCommand; # main w/ print-out
if {myCommand()} { puts "then, here" }; # wrapper w/o print-out

set x [myCommand]; # main w/ print-out, x is set to ""
set y [expr {myCommand()}]; # wrapper w/o print-out, y is set to result
```

All this relies on the special-purpose namespace [`::tcl::mathfunc`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcl%3A%3Amathfunc) and how commands/ procs therein are treated by `[expr]`. Benefits to me are:

- Allows for a straight-forward refactoring (your main command gets simpler) and the wrapper is purely scripted.
- Clear separation of usage contexts, even syntactically.
- No need for introspecting on the `CmdFrame`/`CallFrame` context of your command, which would be limited anyways and would require access to Tcl internals.
- There is no introspection penality on each and every call onto your command.

---

### Original suggestions

Are you after sth. along the (scripted) lines of:

```
proc myCommand {} {
    for {set i 1} {$i<=[info frame]} {incr i} {
        set frameInfo [info frame $i]
        set frameType [dict get $frameInfo type]
        set cmd [dict get $frameInfo cmd]
        if {$frameType eq "source" && [lindex $cmd 0] eq "if"} {
           puts stderr {Called from (anywhere) within [if]}
           break;
        }
    }
    return 1
}

myCommand;
# some ancestor stackframe might reveal some [if] context
if {[myCommand]} { puts "then, here!"};
```

You can achieve sth. similar on the C side by using `TclGetFrame`, to obtain the current stackframe, and by then climbing the down the stack. However, as Donal clearly states, this has a very strong smell and might incur many false positives (e.g., `[myCommand]` anywhere in `if` structure, `if` not  necessarily denoting the so-named control-flow structure, in case someone decided to piggyback onto this command name etc.)

Better re-assess why you sense the need of doing so, in the first place.

> The thing is I don't know what to do later cause I can't print command
>   result if it is inside [] brackets etc.

For example, it remains unclear to me what makes a difference to your command's clients whether it is called in an `if`-context, or not. It should not make a difference, as Donal also writes.

If you want to print out the return value of `myCommand` in the `if`-condition, without altering the behaviour, then write sth. like in your script (rather than manipulating the command itself):

```
if {[set tmp [myCommand]; puts $tmp; set tmp]} { puts "then, here!"};
```

### Update

If you do not want to manipulate the script (at the call site of `myCommand`), then use an [execution trace](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9) to watch your `myCommand` executions:

```
proc logMyCommand {call code result op} {
    # puts ...
}

trace add execution myCommand leave logMyCommand
```

Comment: Some more background: You obtain identical levels (in the sense of `info level`), because `if`-scripts and the surrounding script are executed at the same callstack level (e.g., for the same variable scope). Mind the difference between [callstack levels and callstack frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041783/tcl-info-level-vs-info-frame)

Comment: Actually It is not a bug that clients complain about, but colleague from work gave me this task to look at it and it is rather about the look, so it is: "I shouldn't print command result if it is inside [] brackets etc." Anyway, thank you for the answer I will try to make it tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of data should I check in my code, I updated the question again could you look at it?

Comment: @A.Michałek I tried to come up with some concrete suggestions, but the general advise is to re-think the problem and take it from a different angle (see my suggestion for improvement.)

Comment: I don't know how to acknowledge you for your help. It helped me a lot. Now I understand it clearly. I simply thought that maybe there is another solution of how to detect a nested evaluation but now as you said again it is impossible I have to do sth else. Also, I will try with your suggestion for improvment. Thanks man.

Comment: Accept my answer, for a start ;) And get back to us when you have a clear sight on your objective, report back whether one of the alternative suggestions works for you ...

Comment: Would you like to answer another question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302415/tcl-embedded-does-tcl-autocompletes-commands

Answer (score 0):

The `Tcl_SetResult` function is used to set the result field of the interpreter to the given string value. (The field is entirely internal in all recent versions of Tcl, and is actually multiple real fields in order to handle memory management and so on. These are details you can ignore.) If a command does not set the result, its result *from a Tcl perspective* will be the empty string. You don't need to set the result for any other reason, though the interpretation of the result field will vary: if the command produces an error (by its implementation function returning `TCL_ERROR` instead of `TCL_OK`) then the result field contains the error *message*. When a command is called, the value of the result field is (observationally equivalent to) an empty string.

There's no general way to tell from the API what a command produces: it just produces a value (which is logically a string, as that is the logical supertype of all other types of values understood by Tcl). The documentation of a command, where it exists, may be more specific. All Tcl's built-in commands should be clear about what they produce, and should predictably produce error messages if not in a situation where they are documented to produce a successful result. Commands not provided by Tcl itself are not so constrained; we can't force you to use the API correctly!

---

It's considered ***extremely bad style*** to change the behaviour of a command depending on what its calling context is, except in gross ways (e.g., because you're in a different namespace or in a procedure). In particular, you can't tell if a call is happening inside an `if`, either inside the expression part or inside one of the body scripts. When you need to discriminate that, either tell the command via an explicit argument to it, or split the command in two with different names. A side benefit of this is that it makes your code much easier to test.