# Embedded Tcl: Does Tcl autocomplete commands?

Tags: c++, command, embedded, tcl

We have a Tcl **built in** our C/C++ application, I found the place in our code where **Tcl_EvalObjv** is called if the command was not found. I have to admit that the code is pretty old and not many of our developers know what happens in this module.

It looks like this:

```
// ... there is some checking if command is registered etc., it fails and the code goes here:
std::vector<Tcl_Obj*> tclArgs = { NULL };
for (int i = 1; i < objc; ++i)
    tclArgs.push_back(objv[i]);
tclArgs.shrink_to_fit();
// ...
tclArgs[0] = ::Tcl_NewStringObj(ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN, ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN_SIZE);
Tcl_IncrRefCount(tclArgs[0]);
::Tcl_ExposeCommand(pInterp, ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN, ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN);
result = ::Tcl_EvalObjv(pInterp, objc, &tclArgs[0], TCL_EVAL_GLOBAL); //<--
::Tcl_HideCommand(pInterp, ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN, ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN);
// ORIGINAL_UNKNOWN is char* it is just "unknown"
```

We have handlers for commands in our application, while executing **Tcl_EvalObjv** in **CmdUnknown()** function **Tcl** sometimes calls different commands. Examples below:

List of existing commands: "banana", "applepie", "carpet", "card"

**Command: "apple", Tcl calls "applepie" (wrong, "apple" is not "applepie")**
 
Command: "blah", Tcl gives error (correctly).
Command: "car", Tcl gives error (correctly, maybe because of 2 similar commands).
Is there are some kind of mechanism that **Tcl** does when it fails in searching for command? The thing is that I can't find anything that is related to our code that would complete the commands so maybe **Tcl** does?

Comment: I don't know where this is documented, but the user only needs to provide the minimum prefix of the command so that it is unambiguous: `a` is sufficient to differentiate "applepie" from the other commands. Similarly, `b`, `carp` and `card` are unambiguous command prefixes.

Comment: Now I wonder if there is a way of turning it off. So I guess I have to add special character after the command like "apple#" then if an error is returned find this character and remove it. But maybe such a function exists in tcl or flag to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As glenn hinted at, Tcl in [interactive (REPL) mode](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcl%5Finteractive) allows for dispatching commands using some minimal but unambiguous name prefix. I cannot tell how your embedded Tcl is configured, initialised, and ended up being run as in interactive mode. However, you may want to try to "turn off" (toggle) the interactive mode, by either:

```
unset ::tcl_interactive
```

or

```
set ::tcl_interactive 0
```

All of this is implemented by the default `unknown` handler. Watch out for how the list of `cmds` is looked up and how it is treated differently when `tcl_interactive` is true or false:

```
puts [info body unknown]
```

Comment: For a try: Put `Tcl_SetVar(interp, "tcl_interactive", "0", TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);` anywhere before `Tcl_EvalObjv` is called.

Comment: Thanks, it will be checked tomorrow ;)