# Parent TCL procedure

Tags: tcl

let's say you have a TCL procedure ProcA and a TCL script ScrpB.
ProcA sources ScrpB.
How can I know, from within ScrpB, that ProcA sourced it?

Thank you

I tried the folowing.
From within ScrpB called to "info frame" and did get any usefule info.

Comment: You are looking for info level 0 - see this question answered by Donal Fellows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041783/tcl-info-level-vs-info-frame

Answer (score 3):

`info level 0` is specifically what you are looking for. You can browse the entire calling stack by adding something like this in the called proc:

```
for {set i [info level]} {$i > 0} {set i [expr {$i - 1}]} {
    lappend stack [info level $i]          
}
return $stack
```

Comment: a touch of code review: `set i [expr {$i - 1}]` can be written as `incr i -1`

Comment: Note that it's usually bad form to significantly change behaviour based on the identity of the caller. Doing that sort of thing makes code much harder to debug.